# Will any one help me what is wrong with this query?

Tags: jpa

I am new to JPA and I am trying to get some data with in clause but I am getting 0 value.

```
public Collection<Plant> findAllPlants(BigDecimal uId) throws DAOException {
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery(""
                    + "SELECT p FROM Plant p "
                    + "WHERE p.plantId IN ("
                    + "SELECT up.userplantPK.plantId FROM Userplant up "
                    + "WHERE up.userplantPK.userId IN (?1))");
            query.setParameter(1, uId);
            return query.getResultList();
        }
```

here instead of getting Collection of plant with some size , I am getting 0 size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(""
                + "SELECT p FROM Plant p "
                + "WHERE p.plantId IN ("
                + "SELECT up.userplantPK.plantId FROM Userplant up "
                + "WHERE up.userplantPK.userId = :uId)");
        query.setParameter("uId", uId);
```

Also, check that `uId` parameter and `userId` attribute are the same type.

Good luck!